# Why am I getting Multiple Types in One Declaration?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Here is my class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gameobject.h"
#include "IXmlAssigner.h"

#ifndef CHARACTER_H
#define CHARACTER_H
//line 7...
enum Race {HUMAN, DARK_ELF};
enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE};

class Character : public GameEntity, protected IXmlAssigner
{
public:
    Character();
    Character(std::string xmlCharID);
    ~Character();

    int get_id();
    std::string get_name();
    Race get_race();
    Gender get_gender();

    virtual void assign_xml(std::string xmlCharID);

protected:
    int char_id;
    static int char_count;
    std::string name;
    Race race;
    Gender gender;
};

#endif // CHARACTER_H
```

On line 7, it states the "multiple types in one declaration" error. Why is this? Is there anything I can do to change it?

Comment: Which line is line 7? Line 7 looks like a blank line to me.

Comment: I commented it in the code. Why this is happening beats me. I'm using QT creator by the way.

Comment: What's in `gameobject.h`? Could be you forgot a `;` at the end of a class in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include "gameobject.h"
#include "IXmlAssigner.h"
```

Most likely you're missing a `;` at the end of a class or structure declaration at the end of one of these headers.

Comment: Thank you...still getting used to c++.